# What is the simplest way to create an empty iterable using yield in Python?

Tags: python, iterator, yield

I was playing around with iterables and more specifically the `yield` operator in Python. While using test driven development to start writing a new iterable, I wondered what is the shortest code that could make this simple test for an iterable to pass:

```py
def test():
    for x in my_iterable():
        pass
```

The shortest version I could think of was:

```py
def my_iterable():
    for i in []:
        yield i
```

Is it possible to write a simpler, shorter or more beautiful (pythonic) version?

Comment: Note that if your test iterable is empty and doesn't produce anything -- as shown and in most or all of the answers -- your test won't exercise any of the code in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Another solution, in Python 3, is to use the new `yield from` syntax:

```
def empty_gen():
    yield from ()
```

Which is readable, and keep `empty_gen` as a generator.

Comment: **This is it.** While answers like `lambda: iter(())` satisfy man's instinctual drive for cleverness, they're also unreadable and fail to produce an actual *generator.* In particular, `isinstance(iter(()), types.GeneratorType) == False`. As the relative success of [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) shows, types sometimes *do* matter. Always `yield from`, Python 3 people.

Answer (score 43):

Yes, there is:

```
return iter([])
```

Comment: that's nice but I got: `F999` warning

Comment: You may want to consider the pythonic [`yield from ()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36658865/3077939) instead.

Comment: `[]` creates a new object every time the expression is evaluated. It is better to use empty tuple instead `()`. Empty tuple can even be a singleton (not guaranteed) - every empty tuple refers to the same object.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the lambda and iter functions to create an empty iterable in Python.

```
my_iterable = lambda: iter(())
```

Answer (score 11):

How about

```
my_iterable = str
```

this passes your test.

To speak seriously, `Iterable` in the [collections module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/_abcoll.py) provides:

```
def __iter__(self):
    while False:
        yield None
```

This can be considered "most pythonic" because this is what python itself uses.

Note that technically all answers so far provide *iterators* (`__iter__` + `next`), not *iterables* (just `__iter__`).

Comment: Accepted because of reference to Python standard library.

Comment: That makes me curious.  Why is `str` iterable?

Comment: @DanielWalker You can iterate over the characters in the string.

Comment: @MEMark, yes, but you can't iterate over `str` itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
def do_yield():
    return
    yield None
```

if usage of `yield` is important for you, one of the other answers otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, as I provide a completely new solution with a different approach.

In one of by libraries, I have an `EmptyIterator` such as

```
class EmptyIter(object):
    __name__ = 'EmptyIter'
    """Iterable which is False and empty"""
    def __len__(self): return 0
    def next(self): raise StopIteration # even that is redundant
    def __getitem__(self, index): raise IndexError
```

It is an alternative approach which uses the following properties:

- alternative iteration via the sequence protocol (see [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter))
- alternative "falseness" protocol as described [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__).